# transferring old Xbox files to new a 250GB drive

Tags: xbox-360, hard-drive

I'm transferring old Xbox files to a new 250GB drive and the optical media update did not transfer. What can I do about this?

Comment: Do you mean the optional media update to play unprotected files?

Answer (score 2):

If you mean the Optional Media Update to play unprotected AAC format music files, you can add it to your download queue here:

http://marketplace.xbox.com/en-US/Product/Optional-Media-Update/66acd000-77fe-1000-9115-d802fffe07df